# Overwrite a url config file using Sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed, environment-variables

I have a flag on a file

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

I want to update it to

```
APP_URL=http://aws.test
```

I want to overwrite it, I tried

```
sed -i -e 's/APP_URL=http://localhost/APP_URL=http://aws.test/g' .env
```

and

```
sed -i -e 's/APP_URL="http://localhost"/APP_URL="http://aws.test"/g' .env
```

I kept getting

> sed: 1: "s/APP_URL="http://local ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'l'

How would one go about debugging this further?

Comment: Use different delimiters, e.g. `,`. `sed -i -e 's,APP_URL=http://localhost,APP_URL=http://aws.test,g' .env`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many forwardslashes in your command.  Either escape the ones in the url with `\/` or use a different separator for sed, ie:

```
sed 's#replace/this/string#with/this/one#g'
```